# same origin policy not working

Tags: javascript, html, cross-domain, same-origin-policy

I am trying to understand the same origin policy with a small demo that i have created. But somehow something is going wrong. Below are the html files on 2 different domains (virtual domains that i hosted in XAMP) :-

> domain1.com

```
<html>
<title>
 DOMAIN1.COM
</title>
<script>
 function showTheirSecret() 
 {
var   stolenSecret=document.getElementById('stealSecret').contentWindow.document.getElementsByName("mySecret")[0].value;
if (stolenSecret)
{
    alert("Script on this page accessed the secret box and says "+stolenSecret);
}
else
    alert("Script on this page can not access the secret box!! ");  
}
</script>
<body>
  WELCOME TO <h1>domain1.com</h1><br>
  This is the contents on domain1.com. <br>
  These can not be accessed by domain2.com
  <br>
  <br>
  <iframe id="stealSecret"  src="http://localhost/~user/training/domain2.com/"></iframe>
  <br>
  <br>
  <h2>
  Click the "ok" button to see domain 2's secret text.
  </h2>
  <input type="button" value="stealData" onclick="javascript:showTheirSecret()">
  </body>
</html>
```

> domain2.com

```
<html>
<title>
  DOMAIN2.COM
</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
function showMe() 
{
var secret=document.getElementsByName("mySecret")[0].value;
if(secret)
{
    alert("Script on this page accessed the secret box and says "+secret);
}
else
    alert("Script on this page can not access the secret box!! ");
}
 </script>
 <body>
   WELCOME TO <h1>domain2.com</h1><br>
   This is the contents on domain2.com. <br>
   These can not be accessed by domain1.com
   <br>
   <h2> 
   Put your secret text here !! 
   </h2> &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;
   <h2>
Click the "ok" button to see your own text.
</h2>
<input type="password" name="mySecret" value ="">
<input type="button" value="ok" onclick="javascript:showMe()">
</body>
```

Now lets say I am on domain1.com and in the iframe (that holds domain2.com), i put in some text in the text box in the iframe. Now i click on the "stealData" button. So ideally, what I am expecting here is that the same origin policy should kick in and i should not be allowed to access the contents of the text box in the iframe. And the same should be visible as an error in the java script console in Firefox. But this does not really happen. WHY ?

Comment: In the question you talk about "domain1.com" and "domain2.com", but in your HTML you have `<iframe src="http://localhost/...` - are you sure you're actually serving your two files from different domains?

Comment: Well, i think i might just be wrong there as well. I was suspecting that. But, I am not sure how to get 2 different virtual domains in Mac on XAMPP. I followed the steps here :-
http://f6design.com/journal/2012/03/11/configuring-virtualhosts-in-xampp-on-mac/
But, I am not sure if it worked for me. Am new to Mac and XAMP. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to all. After going through RichieHIndle's comment, I realized it was a mistake in setting up the domains itself. My httpd-vhosts.conf entries for my domains were incorrect. Rectifying this file did the job and I got what I was expecting. I could see the same origin policy in action.